# Disable default Copy&Paste behaviour in Bash

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

When I paste into my terminal session the shell immediately executes the command without me pressing the enter key.

I really don't know how to disable that behaviour.

I'm using the preinstalled terminal on MacOS Yosemite.

Comment: It does that only, of course, if the paste buffer contains a newline. This has (almost) nothing to do with bash. (It concerns bash only if and as far as it uses the readline library.)

Comment: ... and yet `bash` (with the help of `readline`) has a fix.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, but for some reason `zsh` works around that. Please let's not act like this is the norm that we have to accept.

Comment: @MartinBraun Since bash is the norm ... ;-). Anyway, my new msys2 installations do not execute commands any longer, even though `enable-bracketed-paste` does not seem explicitly set.

Comment: By the way, some time ago I investigated this a bit more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654284/3150802). Apparently, msys2 now does this by default, [perhaps in a mintty setting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70356110/3150802) (even though I don't see anything in the mintty options, and it seems wrong for the terminal to do that, doesn't it?).

Comment: Regarding "it seems wrong for the terminal to do that": Actually, *only the terminal* can bracket the input since only the terminal is aware of how the text is entered; the purpose of the escape sequences is precisely to let the program receiving the data know that it was bracketed, since there is no other way for the program to know that.

Comment: Ah, this appears to have been [disabled by default in readline 8.1](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/CHANGES) (changes in 8.1, h.).

Comment: ... for the better.

Answer (score 18):

With `bash` 4.4 or newer and in terminals that support bracketed paste a la `xterm`, you can do:

```
bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste'
```

(or add `set enable-bracketed-paste` to your `~/.inputrc`)

That will cause the copy-paste buffer to be inserted at the prompt instead of the characters in it to be interpreted as if typed (you could still have problems if that buffer contains characters like `^C`, `^Z` and your terminal emulator doesn't filter them out).

`zsh` does that by default since version 5.1.

For other shells or terminals, see also: [How can I protect myself from this kind of clipboard abuse?](//security.stackexchange.com/q/39118)

Comment: I'll look right into it

Comment: booth ways doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Opaldes, what did you try? With what version of what shell and on what terminals? I beleive OS/X also ships with `xterm`, you could try that instead. Have you tried the `perl` script at the linked question?

Comment: @Opaldes, according to [Pasting code into terminal window into vim on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7053522) OS/X Terminal supports bracketed paste since OS/X Lion. So it would seem all you need is a recent enough version of zsh or bash. With older zsh versions, that can also be achieved via configuration.

Comment: I tried " bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste' " in my terminal session. Created an inputrc with "bind set enable-bracketed-paste" at  ~/.inputrc.
I'll look up how to update my terminal on MacOS and will tell you if it works

Comment: @Opaldes, is your version of bash 4.4 (alpha) or newer (`echo "$BASH_VERSION"`)? It won't work with earlier versions. Note that 4.4 is currently on its second release candidate, it's not officially released yet. zsh 5.1 has been out for a while though, and whatever (probably older) version of zsh OS/X ships with by default, you'll be able to use the safe-paste plugin mentioned at the security.SE Q&A I link to. With any shell, you should also be able to use the perl script I gave there.

Comment: 3.2.57(1)-release is the value of $BASH_VERSION. I'll try to implement your perl script.

Comment: We can thank Daniel Colascione for adding this useful feature to Bash/Readline: http://gnu-bash.2382.n7.nabble.com/PATCH-bracketed-paste-support-td14367.html

Comment: Already at bash 5 on macOS, still not working for me. Weirdly enough, pasting `bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste'` to my terminal worked once for the session, now it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

This happens when you paste a "newline" character. For example, if you're pasting multiple lines or you unknowningly copy a carriage return at the end of the line. AFAIK there's no way to actually disable this behaviour but there are ways to mitigate it.

The easiest way is to just copy one line at a time and miss off the last character, manually adding it afterwards.

Or, as the_velour_fog points out below, you could also paste it into an editor that shows non-printed characters and reselect without the newline.

There's one or two workarounds floating around for GNU/Linux distros but no idea if the concept could be ported over to MacOS. Regardless, take a look [here](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95548) and see if there's a similar file in mac that you could alter. Unfortunately, I doubt it.

Comment: I just paste it into an editor that shows non-printed characters, then reselect without the newline

Comment: Good suggestion, edited to include.

Comment: good to know that explains that it happens not all the time. I upvoted your answer but it is more a workaround as a solution to me.

Comment: It's a pain but can be useful when copying a series of commands.

Comment: My "solution" is also sort of a hack workaround, but it's faster than selecting separately, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

**Before pasting, type a single-quote**, then paste.  control-c and up-arrow to edit it as one giant line.

double-quotes also work, in case the text contains single but not double quotes.  It's ok if it contains `$` or other things that expand inside double quotes, because you're not actually running the quoted giant line as one command.

---

You can't actually edit the whole thing right there, because newlines do start a continuation prompt (not the official terminology) instead of making one big long line.

given these 4 lines:

```
echo
ls
foo
bar
```

pasting as I suggest will result in this on your screen:

```
$ 'echo 
> ls
> foo
> bar        <or cursor here if you didn't include a trailing newline
> [cursor here]
```

You can then press control-C and up-arrow.  (control-C destroys everything on the same line as the cursor, so press return first if there's useful text there.)

An alternative is to close the quote and press return, then up-arrow that.

Anyway, **after up-arrow**

```
$ 'echo
ls
foo
bar
```

control-a and remove the leading `'`.  Use control-left and control-right to move quickly through the paste block (by words).  Or if your terminal setup doesn't support control-arrow-keys, alt-b and alt-f.

---

**The literal newlines do actually separate commands, and these 4 lines will go into your command history separately**.  You might want to change them to `;` or `&&`.  (I don't know a trick for that, just use key-repeat for forward or backward-word to get there quickly and do it manually.)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your paste ends with a newline, and terminal emulators basically feed the paste to bash character by character. In this process, bash doesn't know human typist from a machine really.

I usually just pay extra attention when doing copy-pasting that it doesn't include a newline, but there's one trick that you can try: before paste, in bash, type in `C-x C-e`. It should launch `$EDITOR` with an empty file. Whatever you save in that file and exit, bash will execute. So you can now paste your command to the editor, possibly manipulate things further and then run them all in one go.

Answer (score -1):

I am **NOT** related to the company, I am a very satisfied customer. Try this terminal program: http://www.emtec.com/zoc/index.html. There is also a Mac version available.

If I violate with this answer any SE rule please let me know and I delete the answer.

**Edit:**

When I understood the other answers correctly this problem may be caused by the terminal program. The ZOC terminal program is a professional software which is perfectly designed for the work. It pastes the text you selected without any additional character. You can log your sessions in a separate text file. And lot more

**Update:**

The terminal program has an option `Paste without final 'newline'`. May be this helps.

Comment: Please at least say how it answers the question

Comment: If you paste a string that contains newline or carriage-return characters at the prompt of a shell running in that terminal, what happens? If it doesn't cause the shell to execute the commands straight-away (as asked here), how does it do it? Does it remove those characters from the selection? Does it insert a ^V character  before to _escape_ it for bash?

Comment: As such, it looks more like spam (though I'm sure it wasn't your intention to spam this site). It doesn't answer the question and is just advertisement for a related commercial product.

Comment: @AlBundy, find out if your favorite terminal client solves this problem by trying out the exploits discussed in http://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118 (mentioned in Stephane's answer), and the links you'll find there. If it protects you, you have good grounds to recommend it (do provide the details of your tests in your answer.).

Comment: Usually the problem is that what you selected *does* include a newline.  How is "pastes the text you selected" any different from the normal behaviour of any other terminal emulator?